# Scrapy crawler to pass multiple item classes to pipeline

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Hi i am very new to Python and Scrapy, this is my first code and i cant solve a problem that looks pretty basic.

I have the crawler set to do two things:
1- Find all pagination URLs, visit them and get some data from each page
2- Get all links listed on the results pages, visite them and crawl for each location data

I am taking the decision of each item to parse using rules with callback.
I created to classes inside items.py for each parser

The second rule is processing perfect but the first is not being processed and i cant find where is the error.

The error message that i am getting in the terminal running the crawler

```
    2014-11-24 02:30:39-0200 [apontador] ERROR: Error processing {'city': u'BR-SP-S\xe3o Paulo',
     'coordinates': {'lat': u'-23.56588', 'lng': u'-46.64777'},
    'current_url': 'http://www.apontador.com.br/local/search.html?q=supermercado&loc_z=S%C3%A3o+Paulo%2C+SP&loc=S%C3%A3o+Paulo%2C+SP&loc_y=S%C3%A3o+Paulo%2C+SP',
    'datetime': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 24, 2, 30, 39, 703972),
    'depth': 0,
    'domain': 'apontador.com.br',
     'link_cat': 'ls',
     'loc_cat': u'supermercado',
     'session_id': -1,
     'site_name': u'Apontador',
     'state': u'BR-SP'}
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 62, in _process_chain
        return process_chain(self.methods[methodname], obj, *args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 65, in process_chain
        d.callback(input)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 382, in callback
        self._startRunCallbacks(result)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 490, in _startRunCallbacks
        self._runCallbacks()
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "/locman/scrapy/locman/pipelines.py", line 37, in process_item
        'neighborhood': item['neighborhood'],
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/item.py", line 50, in __getitem__
        return self._values[key]
    exceptions.KeyError: 'neighborhood'
```

Looking at error message looks clear that scrapy is trying to process all the items in items.py, not respecting the defined item class called by each callback.

If you see the file items.py there are two classes: 1- apontadorlsItem, 2- apontadordsItem

The class apontadordsItem has the key 'neighborhood' but the item class apontadorlsItem does not have the key 'neighborhood'. I created this two classes to support two different callback parser functions depending on the xpath rule. I did this because there are two types of pages being crawled with differents sets of information on each. The rules are working fine as i can see on the log files, the crawler is working, the problem is on processing/saving it!

How can i declare to pipeline to use different item matching rule depending on the source items.py class that was used by the crawler.

Please help, i got stuck

Spider file - spiders/apontador.py

```py
from datetime import datetime

from locman.items import apontadordsItem
from locman.items import apontadorlsItem
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from tld import get_tld


class apontador(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'apontador'
    session_id = -1
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.apontador.com.br/local/search.html?q=supermercado&loc_z=S%C3%A3o+Paulo%2C+SP&loc=S%C3%A3o+Paulo%2C+SP&loc_y=S%C3%A3o+Paulo%2C+SP"]
    rules = (
        # Rule for LS - Link source - Search results page
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("",), restrict_xpaths=("//nav[@class='pagination']")), callback='parse_items_ls',
             follow=True),

        # Rule for DS - Data Source - Location data page
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("",), restrict_xpaths=(
            "//article[@class='poi card highlight']",
            "//li[@class='similar-place sponsored']",
            "//div[@class='recomendations']",
            "//ul[@class='similar-places-list']",
            "//article[@class='poi card']")),
             callback='parse_items_ds',
             follow=True),
    )

    def __init__(self, session_id=-1, *args, **kwargs):
        super(apontador, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.session_id = session_id

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        self.response_url = response.url
        return self.parse_items_ls(response)

    # Callback item type LS
    def parse_items_ls(self, response):
        self.response_url = response.url
        sel = Selector(response)
        items_ls = []
        item_ls = apontadorlsItem()
        item_ls["session_id"] = self.session_id
        item_ls["depth"] = response.meta["depth"]
        item_ls["current_url"] = response.url

        # Get site name in metadata
        meta_site = sel.xpath("//meta[@property='og:site_name']/@content").extract()
        item_ls["site_name"] = u''.join(meta_site)

        # Get latitude and longitude in metadata
        meta_latitude = sel.xpath("//meta[@name='apontador:latitude']/@content").extract()
        latitude = ''.join(meta_latitude)

        meta_longitude = sel.xpath("//meta[@name='apontador:longitude']/@content").extract()
        longitude = ''.join(meta_longitude)

        # Convert the coordinates to an array
        coordinates = {"lng": longitude, "lat": latitude}
        item_ls["coordinates"] = coordinates

        # This items gets the strings directly from meta data keywords and creates a list
        meta_keywords_ls = sel.xpath("//meta[@name='keywords']/@content").extract()
        meta_keywords_ls_str = u''.join(meta_keywords_ls)
        meta_keywords_ls_list = meta_keywords_ls_str.split(", ")
        meta_state = meta_keywords_ls_list[6]
        meta_city = meta_keywords_ls_list[5]
        meta_loc_cat = meta_keywords_ls_list[4]

        item_ls["state"] = u"BR-" + meta_state
        item_ls["city"] = u"BR-" + meta_state + "-" + meta_city
        item_ls["loc_cat"] = meta_loc_cat

        # This items gets the domain name using the TLD module
        domain = get_tld(response.url)
        item_ls["domain"] = domain

        # This items gets datetime
        item_ls["datetime"] = datetime.now()

        # This items defines de link category        
        item_ls["link_cat"] = "ls"
        yield item_ls

    # Callback item type DS
    def parse_items_ds(self, response):
        self.response_url = response.url
        sel = Selector(response)
        items_ds = []
        item_ds = apontadordsItem()
        item_ds["session_id"] = self.session_id
        item_ds["depth"] = response.meta["depth"]
        item_ds["current_url"] = response.url

        # Get site name in metadata
        meta_site = sel.xpath("//meta[@property='og:site_name']/@content").extract()
        item_ds["site_name"] = u''.join(meta_site)

        # Get location name in metadata
        meta_loc_name = sel.xpath("//meta[@property='og:title']/@content").extract()
        item_ds["loc_name"] = u''.join(meta_loc_name)

        # Get location source id in metadata
        meta_loc_source_id = sel.xpath("//meta[@name='apontador:place-id']/@content").extract()
        item_ds["loc_source_id"] = ''.join(meta_loc_source_id)

        # Get location street address in metadata
        meta_loc_address = sel.xpath("//meta[@property='business:contact_data:street_address']/@content").extract()
        meta_loc_address_str = u''.join(meta_loc_address)
        meta_loc_address_list = meta_loc_address_str.split(", ")
        meta_loc_address_number = meta_loc_address_list[1]
        meta_loc_address_street = meta_loc_address_list[0]
        item_ds["loc_street"] = meta_loc_address_street
        item_ds["loc_number"] = meta_loc_address_number

        # Get latitude and longitude in metadata
        meta_latitude = sel.xpath("//meta[@property='place:location:latitude']/@content").extract()
        latitude = ''.join(meta_latitude)

        meta_longitude = sel.xpath("//meta[@property='place:location:longitude']/@content").extract()
        longitude = ''.join(meta_longitude)

        coordinates = {"lng": longitude, "lat": latitude}
        item_ds["coordinates"] = coordinates

        # This items gets the neighborhood, loc_cat, loc_sub_categoryfrom meta data keywords, creates a list and populates the fields from the list
        meta_keywords_ds = sel.xpath("//meta[@name='keywords']/@content").extract()
        meta_keywords_ds_str = u''.join(meta_keywords_ds)
        meta_keywords_ds_list = meta_keywords_ds_str.split(", ")
        meta_loc_cat = meta_keywords_ds_list[9]
        meta_loc_cat_sub = meta_keywords_ds_list[8]
        meta_neighborhood = meta_keywords_ds_list[5]

        item_ds["loc_cat"] = meta_loc_cat
        item_ds["loc_cat_sub"] = meta_loc_cat_sub
        item_ds["neighborhood"] = meta_neighborhood

        # Region informations
        meta_statec = sel.xpath("//meta[@property='business:contact_data:region']/@content").extract()
        meta_state = u''.join(meta_statec)
        item_ds["state"] = u"BR-" + meta_state

        meta_cityc = sel.xpath("//meta[@property='business:contact_data:locality']/@content").extract()
        meta_city = u''.join(meta_cityc)
        item_ds["city"] = u"BR-" + meta_state + "-" + meta_city

        meta_postal_code = sel.xpath("//meta[@property='business:contact_data:postal_code']/@content").extract()
        item_ds["loc_postal_code"] = ''.join(meta_postal_code)

        # This items gets the domain name using the TLD module
        domain = get_tld(response.url)
        item_ds["domain"] = domain

        # This items gets datetime as an i
        item_ds["datetime"] = datetime.now()

        item_ds["link_cat"] = "ds"
        yield item_ds
```

Items file - items.py

```py
    from scrapy.item import Item, Field

    class apontadorlsItem(Item):
        datetime = Field()
        session_id = Field()
        depth = Field()
        link_cat = Field()
        site_name = Field()
        domain = Field()
        current_url = Field()
        city = Field()
        state = Field()
        loc_cat = Field()
        coordinates = Field()

    class apontadordsItem(Item):
        datetime = Field()
        session_id = Field()
        depth = Field()
        link_cat = Field()
        site_name = Field()
        domain = Field()
        current_url = Field()
        state = Field()
        city = Field()
        neighborhood = Field()
        loc_name = Field()
        loc_street = Field()
        loc_number = Field()
        loc_postal_code = Field()
        loc_source_id = Field()
        loc_cat = Field()
        loc_cat_sub = Field()
        coordinates = Field()
```

Pipelines file - pipelines.py

```py
    from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
    from scrapy_mongodb import MongoDBPipeline

    class apontadorpipe(MongoDBPipeline):

        def process_item(self, item, spider):
            if self.config['buffer']:
                self.current_item += 1
                item = dict(item)

                self.item_buffer.append(item)

                if self.current_item == self.config['buffer']:
                    self.current_item = 0
                    return self.insert_item(self.item_buffer, spider)
                else:
                    return item

            matching_item = self.collection.find_one(
                {'datetime': item['datetime'],
                 'session_id': item['session_id'],
                 'depth': item['depth'],
                 'link_cat': item['link_cat'],
                 'site_name': item['site_name'],
                 'domain': item['domain'],
                 'current_url': item['current_url'],
                 'state': item['state'],
                 'city': item['city'],
                 'neighborhood': item['neighborhood'],
                 'loc_name': item['loc_name'],
                 'loc_street': item['loc_street'],
                 'loc_number': item['loc_number'],
                 'loc_postal_code': item['loc_postal_code'],
                 'loc_cat': item['loc_cat'],
                 'loc_cat_sub': item['loc_cat_sub'],
                 'loc_source_id': item['loc_source_id'],
                 'coordinates': item['coordinates']}
            )

            if matching_item is not None:
                raise DropItem(
                    "Duplicate found for %s, %s" %
                    item['current_url']
                )
            else:
                return self.insert_item(item, spider)
```

Settings file - settings.py

```py
    BOT_NAME = 'locman'

    SPIDER_MODULES = 'locman.spiders'
    NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'locman.spiders'
    DEPTH_LIMIT = 10000

    DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS = 'locman.items.apontador'

    ITEM_PIPELINES = {
        'locman.pipelines.apontadorpipe': 100
    }

    # 'scrapy_mongodb.MongoDBPipeline' connection
    MONGODB_URI = 'connection string'
    MONGODB_DATABASE = ''
    MONGODB_COLLECTION = ''

    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
            'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware' : None,
            'locman.ua.rotate_useragent.RotateUserAgentMiddleware' :400
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to store items coming from `parse_items_ls()` callback?

Comment: Yes i want to store items from parse_items_ls() using de class apontadorlsItem in items.py.

Comment: The parse_items_ds() is storing the data to mongoDB, but i am not sure if it is using the class apontadordsItem in items.py

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that item does not have key "neighborhood". make sure following things.

1. you have not misspelled "neighborhood"
2. "neighborhood" is defines in item class
3. item['neighborhood'] is initialized in spider

Make sure that item has key "neighborhood" in File "/locman/scrapy/locman/pipelines.py", line 37, in process_item

```
    if item.get('neighborhood', None):
```

it will return None if item has not key "neighborhood", you can also set default value instead of None like this

```
    if item.get('neighborhood', 'default_value')
```

Comment: Hi Tasawer, i checked all you suggested and i didnt find any of them! The spider is getting the data, i think that the problem is in the pipeline when writing it to mongodb.

Comment: you may have more then one item, so there is a chance that some of item has not value "neighborhood", add a check before getting value of item["neighborhood"], I have improved my answer look at it.. thanks

Comment: hey.. thanks for the help/tips, i will try it and i let you know the results.

Comment: i have updated the question description before the code snippet.

Comment: Hi Tasawer as i said before i am very new to python and i am a bit lost on how and where to implement your solutions! ;-(

Comment: I have already mentioned this in answer add this line at line 37, in process_item pipeline

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for the help! I found a nice workaround for my problem and it is exactly what i needed!

In the `pipeline.py` i imported the two classes from `items.py`, defined 2 different functions and dict for each. This way i can have different duplicate record treatment and different writing processes to the database for each item class!

The new code for `pipeline.py`:

```py
from locman.items import apontadordsItem
from locman.items import apontadorlsItem
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy_mongodb import MongoDBPipeline


class apontadorpipe(MongoDBPipeline):
    def process_item_ds(self, item, spider):
        if self.config['buffer']:
            self.current_item += 1
            item = dict(apontadordsItem)

            self.item_buffer.append(item)

            if self.current_item == self.config['buffer']:
                self.current_item = 0
                return self.insert_item(self.item_buffer, spider)
            else:
                return item

        if isinstance(item, apontadordsItem):
            matching_item = self.collection.find_one(
                {'datetime': item['datetime'],
                 'session_id': item['session_id'],
                 'link_cat': item['link_cat'],
                 'site_name': item['site_name'].encode('utf-8'),
                 'domain': item['domain'],
                 'current_url': item['current_url'],
                 'state': item['state'],
                 'city': item['city'].encode('utf-8'),
                 'neighborhood': item['neighborhood'].encode('utf-8'),
                 'loc_name': item['loc_name'].encode('utf-8'),
                 'loc_street': item['loc_street'].encode('utf-8'),
                 'loc_number': item['loc_number'],
                 'loc_postal_code': item['loc_postal_code'],
                 'loc_cat': item['loc_cat'],
                 'loc_cat_sub': item['loc_cat_sub'],
                 'loc_source_id': item['loc_source_id'],
                 'loc_phone': item['loc_phone'],
                 'address': item['address'].encode('utf-8'),
                 'coordinates': item['coordinates']}
            )

            if matching_item is not None:
                raise DropItem(
                    "Duplicate found for %s, %s" %
                    item['current_url'],
                    item['loc_source_id'],
                )

            else:

                return self.insert_item(item, spider)

    def process_item_ls(self, item, spider):
        if self.config['buffer']:
            self.current_item += 1
            item = dict(apontadorlsItem)

            self.item_buffer.append(item)

            if self.current_item == self.config['buffer']:
                self.current_item = 0
                return self.insert_item(self.item_buffer, spider)
            else:
                return item

        if isinstance(item, apontadorlsItem):
            matching_item = self.collection.find_one(
                {'datetime': item['datetime'],
                 'session_id': item['session_id'],
                 'link_cat': item['link_cat'],
                 'site_name': item['site_name'].encode('utf-8'),
                 'domain': item['domain'],
                 'current_url': item['current_url'],
                 'state': item['state'],
                 'city': item['city'].encode('utf-8'),
                 'loc_cat': item['loc_cat'].encode('utf-8'),
                 'coordinates': item['coordinates']}
            )

            if matching_item is not None:
                raise DropItem(
                    "Duplicate found for %s, %s" %
                    item['current_url'],
                )

            else:

                return self.insert_item(item, spider)
```